# Looking for AWS CLI command to include Public IP, VPC, Instance state & name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, audit

I am trying to extract information for an audit. I recently required a full list of public IP's (which uses the `--query` option) but now I need to filter which IP's belong to instances that are running.

I was previously using:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output=text
```

which generates a lovely list of Public IPs.

Now I need to include a `--filter` option to display which of these IP's are running. I believe the addition would be:

```
--filter Instance-State-Name
```

Not sure where or how this would fit into the command :(

To display the VPC, that the running instances belong to would be great too.

Comment: when instances are not running, they don't have a public IP address (unless you are using EIP)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need something like:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,VpcId,PublicIpAddress,State.Name,Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value]" --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running
```

With table output, it gives:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                             DescribeInstances                            |
+----------------------+---------------+----------------+----------+-------+
|  i-0c963b94b3783ffdc |  vpc-7d287053 |  54.212.107.22 |  running |  Foo  |
+----------------------+---------------+----------------+----------+-------+
```